# how to make a group chat application like facebook

Tags: php, sql, ajax, facebook, chat

i am building a chat application like facebook:
i have try this as a single chat [single chat](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)
i want to integrate group chat in this application.

---

**Questions**

- any other resources for group chat
- any tutorial to make a group chat from scratch

Comment: If you cannot imagine it yourself how to do it, no tutorial would help you

Comment: i have try to modify the script and successfully send the message to the group but i am facing a issue i could not show the group on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

For chat or group chat.. preferable technology is Jabber or e jabbered or openfire.. They all work on XMPP protocol.

Jquery chat is not secure + not scalable.

Study XMPP and ejabbered.. its open source.

Comment: i have done research on xmpp before and could not found a better tutorial can you give me the good tutorial for this..

Comment: https://www.ejabberd.im/tutorials
https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Set_up_a_federated_XMPP_Chat_Network_with_ejabberd.html

Answer (score 1):

> i have try to modify the script and successfully send the message to the group but i am facing a issue i could not show the group on the other side

try to pass the extra object with the request and make a condition on other side to show the group chat on the other side.